# Slider working on iOS not Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I have made a slider that reassembles the iOS slide to unlock, however it doesn't seem to work on Android.
The slider never moves, however you slide it all the way, without the slider following your finger, it will display the alert message.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mfv97/9/

**Edit**

Updated fiddle to work in all (mobile) browsers, though it still doesn't work on my Android phone.

**Edit 2**

I'm using an Optimus 2X with Android 2.3.2 and it doesn't work in both Firefox and the default browser.

Comment: It is not recommended to copy UI elements from iOS to Android verbatim, Android users generally don't forgive app developers who spoil their android experience by forcing iOS look and feel.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it doesn't work, and I **have** to do it this way, even though I agree with you.

Comment: Which Android versions are you testing on? This is obviously a result of the different Webkit versions on the two platforms.